# Android redraw currently displayed fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My case: I have language spinner at MainActivity. FrameLayout with id of `fragment_container`. I change fragments inside. When I change language, fragment doesn't update. I have tried with no result:

```
currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

It return `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference`
Where is my mistake?